# Not able to read input larger than 1024 characters in Go

Tags: go

I am using `fmt.Scanf` to read a string input in Golang. But the command stalls when we pass in a large input (>1024 characters). I am using Go version `go1.8.3 darwin/amd64`.

Here is the code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Here is the payload that fails https://pastebin.com/raw/fJ4QAZUZ

Go seems to take input till `Jy` in that payload which marks 1024 number of characters. So is 1024 a limit or what?

PS - I had already tampered the encoded cookie at that link, so no worries.

Comment: Seems ok to me? https://play.golang.org/p/TaY_XLapeY

Comment: I don't think playground runs `Scanf` command the way it normally runs. It's skipped I think. That example only assigns the large text to `s` and prints it, so it's different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the limit of the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package or [`fmt.Scanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf), this example properly scans more than 3KB:

```
// src is a looooong text (>3KB)

var s string
fmt.Println(len(src))
fmt.Sscanf(src, "%s", &s)
fmt.Println(len(s))
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dK7SE2gCo0)

It's most likely the limit of your terminal. I also tried your unmodified version, pasted more than 10KB of text, and the result was 4096 bytes (Ubuntu linux 16.04, Bash).

Comment: Thank you @icza. This looks to be the correct answer.